# cannot drop a cshtml file on vs.net2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

VS.Net2012 does not accept a  cshtml file to be dropped on it. And when I right click on the cshtml file and select vs.net 2012 to open, it opens a new instance of the vs.net 2012.

Comment: Nothing about this behavior seems strange to me. Its normal if you choose to open a file with Visual Studio that a new instance is started.  You can use any instance of the process and open it using the `File` menu.  What version of Visual Studio 2012 are you using?

Comment: I have the file in the explorer window, so I do not want to copy the path, and run the open file on the Vs.Net 2012, we could do this for like 20 years (I believe starting with VC++ 1.x), what happened now and why we cannot do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I test drag-dropping a .cshtml file on a VS 2012 window it opens up in the VS text editior.

So, it should work. Are you running VS 2012 as administrator? In that case drag-drop to open files doesn't work as it is blocked, probably for security reasons. In this case you get a mouse pointer indicating that the drop operation is blocked when trying to drop the file.

Comment: Yes, I am running it as Administrator, thanks for clarifying this.